# Show that the following is true , my attempt is shown below

Tags: trigonometry

Show that ,
$$\frac{\sin2x-\cos2x-1}{\sin^2x - \cos^2x} = \frac{2}{\tan x+1}$$
My attempt at solving the problem can be seen below
$$LHS = \frac{-(-\sin2x+\cos2x+1)}{-(\cos^2x - \sin^2x)}$$
$$LHS = \frac{(-\sin2x+\cos2x+1)}{(\cos 2x)}$$
$$LHS = \frac{(\cos2x+1-\sin2x)}{(\cos 2x)}$$
$$LHS = 1 + \frac{1}{(\cos2x)}-\tan 2x$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: $\sin2x-\cos2x-1 = 2 \cos x (\sin x - \cos x)$

Comment: After simplifying, divide both numerator and denominator by $\cos x$

Comment: Starting from RHS would be easier

Comment: It can be done by other methods as in comments and answer below. But if you wish to proceed in your method, use these in your last step.
$\cos(2x) = \frac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}$ and $\tan(2x) = \frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are starting from the LHS, you will want to convert double angles to single angles to obtain the RHS:

$$\begin{align}\frac{\sin2x-\cos2x-1}{\sin^2x - \cos^2x}&=\frac{2\sin x\cos x -(2\cos^2 x-1)-1}{\sin^2x - \cos^2x} \\
&=\frac{2\cos x\require{cancel}\bcancel{(\sin x -\cos x)}}{(\sin x+\cos x)\bcancel{(\sin x - \cos x)}}\\
&=\frac{2}{\tan x+1} \end{align}
 $$